# Creating more than one initial route

Tags: flutter, dart

Probably really straight forward but I am trying to create another button on the home page to follow another route.

Currently there is only one button which takes you down path X (aka the First Screen / Home Page) but I would like another button to take you down path Y. Any suggestions please?

Cheers in advance!
(sorry still getting to grips with the terminology)

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
   title: 'Named Routes Demo',
initialRoute: '/',
routes: {
  '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
 '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  '/second/third': (context) => ThirdScreen(),
    },
   )
  );
 }

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Home Page'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Search'),
       onPressed: () {
           Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
             },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

  class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Results Page'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Click this result'),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second/third');
      },
    ),
    ),
  );
}
}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Items Page"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text('This is the item!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using routes, you can use a onGenerateRoute argument

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Named Routes Demo',
      home: FirstScreen(),
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          if(settings.name == '/second/third') return ThirdScreen();
          if(settings.name == '/second') return SecondScreen();
          else return FirstScreen();
        })
      },
    },
   )
  );
 }
```

You can change this logic to any way that you need to use settings.name

To add another button on the homepage, for this simple code, you can use a Column widget, here's the example

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Button one text'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second'),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Button two text'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second/third'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: cheers for the response, how would you go about adding another button to the first screen tho? would that be in the first screen section adding another raised button or in this void main section? cheers

Comment: @h.healy I updated my answer to resolve your concern